# Add File From Nested Dir to Repo Using Pattern Matching

Tags: git

Working with nested dirs, like in an Android project, you can often run into long paths like this:

```
./app/src/main/java/com/something/utilities/SomeClass.java
```

Is there a way to add files using pattern matching, similar to Unix/Linux `find` e.g. `find . -name '*SomeClass.java'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found this solution:

```
git add '*SomeClass.java'
```